# Detect all entities with tag "xyz", if none exist, perform an action

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am designing a minigame where entities will be summoned in, and the objective is to kill them all within a specific time limit. If the limit is reached, the game is over, that's easy - but currently, if all entities are killed, there's no way to end the game.

Is there a way to detect when all entities with a specific tag are killed, take an output (via a comparator) and perform an action based on that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a scoreboard or tag for that. Let's say you have a dummy armour stand somewhere that holds your game scores and other stuff, called "Horst". You have to first give the armour stand a tag if there is any entity of the type you want to detect:

```
/execute @e[type=<mob_you_want>] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players tag @e[name=Horst] add entitiesLeft
```

It can also be anything else, you just need an entity that can have tags and that can be tested for tags. You could just as well use all players (`@a`).

Afterwards, you can execute based on that tag:

```
/execute @e[name=Horst,tag=!entitiesLeft] ~ ~ ~ <command>
```

Comparators are not needed. In general redstone isn't really needed for command block contraptions anymore. You can just make all commands that should depend on this be executed from this `/execute` command.

---

In 1.13 you can do all of this in one command:

```
/execute unless entity @e[type=<mob_you_want>] run <command>
```

Again, repeat for every command that should depend on there being no entites left.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand what's going on here, could you go into more detail about what those commands do, and how to execute them? (Comparator output? Second one on repeat? Just one after the other?)

Comment: Just one after the other. I'll edit the question to include more detail.

Comment: Done. Better now?

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Fabian's answer about not using redstone in command block contraptions, here is a solution that uses comparator output incase that is still what you want.

[image: Command blocks]

The first command block is a <kbd>Repeat</kbd> <kbd>Unconditional</kbd> <kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
testfor @e[tag=xyz]
```

The second command block is <kbd>Impulse</kbd> <kbd>Conditional</kbd> <kbd>Needs Redstone</kbd>.  This command block will run one time when the last entity with the tag xyz has been killed.  This is where you put whatever command you want to run when the game is over.

For this to work successfully, the chunks that the command blocks and entities are in have to remain loaded.  You could contain all of this in the [spawn chunks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_chunk) to be sure they remain loaded.

**Note:** While this solution is simpler then Fabian's answer, it is inferior. The reason it is recommended to avoid using redstone in command block contraptions is because redstone is less reliable then command blocks only.

Comment: It's not about reliability, it's about speed (this takes two redstone ticks, mine 0) and lag.

Comment: This is of course moot since 1.13 has come out, but does it really matter if the Minecraft takes an extra fifth of a second to realize that you've completed a minigame?